# Can't set the application port to run LoRaWAN certification tests

Tags: mbed, lora, lorawan

I'm trying to run LoRaWAN 1.0.4 certification tests on my mDot using LCTT Pre-testing Tool.

I use the latest Dot-AT-Firmware and libmDot v4.0.1.

Looking at the [source code](https://os.mbed.com/teams/MultiTech/code/Dot-AT-Firmware//file/3b696c2b1e4b/CommandTerminal/CommandTerminal.cpp/) (line 918), I added `MTS_RADIO_DEBUG_COMMANDS` and enabled test mode using `AT+TM! 1` command.

The first test that the LCTT tool executes is the Activation Pre-test. Everything goes well up until the last step. When the end device sends `DutVersionsAns`, I see the following message:

> Packet received from unexpected FPort 01

After a few retries, I get another message and the test fails:

> Attempts consumed in sending or receiving a Frame Command

According to the LoRaWAN 1.0.4 End Device Certification Requirement v1.1 document, the End Device must send `DutVersionsAns` on port 224. Looking at the source code again, I see that the application port is indeed set to 224 at line 1409. But when I check the result of `setAppPort()`, it returns -1. If i call `getAppPort()` right after that, I get `port = 1`.

Now, checking the description for [`setAppPort`](https://github.com/MultiTechSystems/libmDot/blob/master/mDot.h#L567):

> Set the device port to be used for lora application data (1-223)

it looks like setting the application port to 224 is illegal...

So, am I doing this wrong? Do I need to do anything else, besides adding `MTS_RADIO_DEBUG_COMMANDS`, to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Port 1 to 223 are used for the application. The port is one byte int the LoRaWAN Protocol. Setting port to 224 is illegal from an application perspective, it is the port for testing.

Have you tried using `setTestModeEnabled(true)` command. I'm assuming it will set the port to 224 or it may allow you to set the port afterwards.

Also note: Ports 225 - 255 are reserved for the future

[See the Specification for further info](https://lora-alliance.org/resource_hub/lorawan-104-specification-package/)

> The purpose of the FPort value 224 is to provide a dedicated FPort to
> run MAC compliance test scenarios over-the-air on final versions of
> end-devices, without having to rely on specific test versions of
> end-devices for practical aspects. The test is not supposed to be
> simultaneous with live operations, but the MAC layer implementation of
> an end-device SHALL be exactly the one used for the normal
> application. The test protocol is encrypted using the AppSKey. This
> ensures that the Network cannot enable the end-device’s test mode
> without involving the end-device’s owner.

Comment: Yes, I tried setTestModeEnabled(true), as well as enabling the test mode through Test.TestMode. Actually, the AT firmware has the test mode implemented, but it was not working. I asked Multitech about this http://www.multitech.net/developer/forums/topic/cant-set-the-application-port-to-run-lorawan-certification-tests/. They said that the libmDot v4.0.1 did not allow the port to be set using setAppPort. I moved to v4.1.0 and it works now.